# Log likelihood from density

Tags: probability, density-function, log-likelihood

Suppose $X_1,…,X_n$ are iid with density $f(x|α)=(α+1)x^αI(x∈[0,1])$,
where $α>−1$ parameterizes the family.

Suppose $x_i∈[0,1]$ for all $i$. I am trying to find the natural log of the density (log likelihood) given the parameter $α$ as a function of $x_1,…,x_n?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density for a sample is

$$f(x|a)=\prod (a+1)x^aI(x_{min}\ge0)I(x_{max}\le1)\\
=(a+1)^n\prod x^aI(x_{min}\ge0)I(x_{max}\le1)$$

Take the log to get the log likelihood

$$\log f(x|a)=n\log(a+1)+a\sum\log x+\log I(x_{min}\ge0)I(x_{max}\le1)$$

(it is undefined if there is a data point not in the support)

Comment: If I wanted to find the Maximum Likelihood as a function of alpha. Do I just take the derivative of the above function?

Comment: Yes, the procedure would be take the derivative wrt alpha and set to 0 to find $\alpha_{MLE}$.